# Recursive algorithm to a simple counting issue

Tags: algorithm, recursion

one item costs one dollar, when we return wrapper of 3 items then we get one more item.
e.g : if we have 15 dollars the we can buy 22 items

1. 15 items
2. 5 items using 5 sets of 3 wrappers
3. 1 item using 3 wrappers(2 wrappers extra)
4. 1 more item using 2 extra wrappers + last one.

I could write a program to calculate the nr. of items can be bought using n dollars. But how to solve it using a recursive relation?

Comment: you will not learn anything by not even trying to solve it yourself, and this sounds like a problem designed only for you to learn something. even if not, please try first to solve it yourself.

Comment: I thought about it, the obvious recurrence relation would work when n is a power of 3.. i.e, f(n) = n+f(n/3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can not return wrappers, you would buy n items with n dollars. Now how many would you get in addition because of returning wrappers? On the first iteration you would get (n / 3) more items and after using those too, you would have (n % 3) + (n / 3) wrappers left(don't forget the n%3 - you may not have returned all the wrappers). Now how many items can you get from returning the wrappers from (n % 3) + (n / 3) items? Denote m = (n % 3) + (n / 3), then you would get (m % 3) + (m / 3). Then you can further return wrappers from these items and so on. Let's denote with a<sub>0</sub>=n the number of wrappers you would have after the first purchase , and then denote with a<sub>i+1</sub> the number of wrappers you would have after returning the wrappers from a<sub>i</sub>. Then you would have a<sub>i+1</sub>=a<sub>i</sub>%3 + a<sub>i</sub>/3 and this is your recursive relation.

Please note that a<sub>i</sub> denotes the number of wrappers you have after each iteration, but adding the numbers a<sub>i</sub> will not result in the total number of items you get but will be more(this is because of the additional a<sub>i</sub>%3). You will have to take care of that when implementing the solution.

Comment: Your answer should and will be removed. Please do not post things that should be comments as answers. This is frowned upon in the community

Comment: frankly, I do not see any problem marking it as an answer, because your hint did not completely specify the recursive relation.  A recursive relation requires much more details and requires IMPORTANTLY two parameters.

Comment: @cobp In fact a<sub>i+1</sub>=a<sub>i</sub>%3 + a<sub>i</sub>/3 is a recursive relation. I will not post a complete solution to the problem as it seems to be either a homework or competition problem. Instead I gave you hints how to solve the problem on your own.

Answer (score 0):

@Ivaylo, thanks for the hint. I was looking for a elegant recursive relation. I hope I could derive it.  A invocation of count(n,n) is the required solution.

```
#w_l      : Wrappers left after each iteration
#cnt_items: Total Count of of items got after each iteration

count(w_l,cnt_items) = count(w_l/3+w_l%3,cnt_items+w_l/3)#wl >= 3
                     = cnt_items                         #w_l <3
```

Comment: Recursive relation above mentioned is the back bone of solution, implementation is just trivial